# Finding mean temperature grouping every N rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with hourly temperatures at different coordinates:

```
df.head
Out[63]: 
time                  latitude  longitude     t2m                                             
2018-01-01 00:00:00      72.0      -11.0  -3.957336
2018-01-01 01:00:00      72.0      -11.0  -4.165466
2018-01-01 02:00:00      72.0      -11.0  -4.562500
2018-01-01 03:00:00      72.0      -11.0  -4.860107
2018-01-01 04:00:00      72.0      -11.0  -5.155762
                      ...        ...        ...
2018-12-31 19:00:00      34.0       32.0  16.527161
2018-12-31 20:00:00      34.0       32.0  16.639832
2018-12-31 21:00:00      34.0       32.0  16.700165
2018-12-31 22:00:00      34.0       32.0  16.592102
2018-12-31 23:00:00      34.0       32.0  16.724670
```

I would like to find the daily mean temperature for each pair of coordinates. For this, I need to group every 24 rows and find the mean of the `t2m` column, while keeping the only the date in the `time` column and the `latitude` and `longitude` columns. That is,

```
df.head
Out[63]: 
time           latitude  longitude        t2m                                               
2018-01-01      72.0       -11.0       -6.378744
2018-01-01      71.75      -11.0       -5.564683
                ...          ...           ...
2018-12-31      33.75       31.75      16.836736
2018-12-31      34.0        32.0       16.836736
```

I tried doing

```
N=24
test=df.groupby(df.index//N).mean()
```

But I got `TypeError: cannot perform __floordiv__ with this index type: DatetimeIndex`. I tried resetting the index and repeating the operation but then it drops the `time` column while adding the rest.

What would be the best way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Using @Shubham Sharma's suggestion, I tried doing

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
N=24
test=df.groupby([df.index//N, 'latitude', 'longitude']).mean()
```

And it finds the right mean value, but it drops entirely the `time` column.

Comment: Check `df.groupby([df.index.date, 'latitude', 'longitude']).mean()`

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, thanks for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It creates an index with date, latitude and longitude but it doesn't add correctly. All the temperatures are negative but I get a positive number bigger than expected.

Comment: Not sure what the problem might be but i think `df.groupby([df.index.date, 'latitude', 'longitude']).mean()` should work fine for the sample data you've presented.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, yes, I don't know what gets added, but as an example, the sum of the first 24 rows should be -150.18542 and I get 420.9158. I edited the question to add something else I tried and it works but it modifies the structure of the dataframe.

Comment: if you want `mean` then don't use `sum()` but `mean()`

Comment: first I would check what you get in groups - maybe some values are similar and  float so they can be be treated as the same value. But as I understand every group should have 24 elements so you could check `len()` for every group.

Comment: can you please indicate `df.dtypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's simpler and more generalizable to use `pd.Grouper(freq='D')`.

From your data snippet, it's not clear whether your dataframe has an index or not. If it has, then `df.head()` (and not `df.head`, BTW) would show:

```
                     latitude  longitude       t2m
time                                     <--- notice the new line                                             
2018-01-01 00:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -3.957336
2018-01-01 01:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -4.165466
2018-01-01 02:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -4.562500
2018-01-01 03:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -4.860107
2018-01-01 04:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -5.155762
```

If it doesn't, then `df.head()` would show the default `RangeIndex`:

```
                 time  latitude  longitude       t2m
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -3.957336
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -4.165466
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -4.562500
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -4.860107
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00      72.0      -11.0 -5.155762
```

In either case:

If `time` is the index, then:

```
out = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'), 'latitude', 'longitude']).mean()
# out:
                                    t2m
time       latitude longitude          
2018-01-01 72.0     -11.0     -4.540234
```

If `time` is just a regular column:

```
out = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='D'), 'latitude', 'longitude']).mean()
# out:
                                    t2m
time       latitude longitude          
2018-01-01 72.0     -11.0     -4.540234
```

In both cases, you can bring the result back from having a `MultiIndex` to being a table-like dataframe:

```
out = out.reset_index()
# out:
        time  latitude  longitude       t2m
0 2018-01-01      72.0      -11.0 -4.540234
```